# Spacing out x-axis labels in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, skew

I'm with MLB salaries and I'm trying to plot a frequency distribution to visualize the skewness of the figure. I'm having trouble making the x-axis labels of my histogram. Btw, I got my MLB salary data from [here](https://plot.ly/alpha/workspace/?fid=egilbert:306).

Here is how I generated my distribution:

```
hist(data, breaks = 33, axes = F)
```

Given my salaries range from 0 to $35 Million, I generated my labels like this -

```
x.axis <- pretty(seq(0,35000000, by = 10000000))/10000000

x.axis
>[1] 0.0 0.5 1.0 1.5 2.0 2.5 3.0
```

Using the axis() function only plots the first 8 labels.

```
axis(1, at = y, labels = paste(y, "M", sep =""))
```

I realize this is because as `length(x.axis) = 8`.

**Is there any way of spacing out the ticks on my x-axis?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm using `at = y` in the axis() function already, but it only plots 8 points along the x-axis, which doesn't cover the span of my distribution.

Comment: The `y` variables are just the frequencies, which I didn't need to define. I guess I don't really need to use `pretty`, I just liked how it adds a decimal point to the x-axis labels.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

```
pts <- pretty(data/10000000)
a <- (seq(0,35000000, by = 5000000))

axis(1, at = a, labels = paste(pts, "M", sep =""))
```

Comment: I completely agree.